# How do I wrap a section of xml in a CDATA tag using Jackson

Tags: java, xml-serialization, jackson

I have the following java object

```
class MyXmlObject{
    @JsonProperty
    private InnerObject innerObject;
    @JsonProperty
    private String someOtherProperty;
}
```

When I serialize this using

```
public String getXmlObjectAsXML(MyXmlObject myXmlObject){
    JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();

    module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper(module);

    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

    String response = "";

    response = mapper.writeValueAsString(myXmlObject);
    return response;
}
```

I would like the InnerObject class to be wrapped in a CDATA tag.

What is the correct way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a similar use case. We needed *all* text fields in our XML wrapped in CDATA. It was a requirement of an API we needed to implement and we had no say in the API.

To solve the problem we created an implementation of @StaxMan's suggestion to override XMLOutputFactory and XMLStreamWriter to hijack `writeCharacters()` and call `writeCData()` instead, and this seems to work great. You can see a Gist of our exact code (with package names changed) here:

https://gist.github.com/jbcpollak/8312151

In brief, we created a `CDataXmlOutputFactoryImpl` class which creates a `CDataXmlStreamWriter`. Unfortunately, rather than using inheritance we needed to wrap the target classes because both were final. Also, the exact writer to use is variable, so wrapping is a safer option.

In the factory, in addition to wrapping all the other methods with pure pass-through functions, you'll need something like this for each createXMLStreamWriter() function (there are 4):

```
public XMLStreamWriter createXMLStreamWriter(Writer w) 
    throws XMLStreamException
{

    return new CDataXmlStreamWriter(f.createXMLStreamWriter(w));
}
```

where `f` is an `OutputFactoryImpl` constructed in the class.

In `CDataXmlStreamWriter` all the necessary functions are pure delegates for the methods in w, except for the two methods below:

```
public void writeCharacters(char[] text, int start, int len) 
    throws XMLStreamException
{
    w.writeCharacters(text, start, len);
}

// All this code just to override this method
public void writeCharacters(String text) throws XMLStreamException
{

    w.writeCData(text);
}
```

Thats about all you need to do. Just use your new factory like this:

```
public void init() {
    XmlFactory factory = new XmlFactory(new InputFactoryImpl(),
            new CDataXmlOutputFactoryImpl());
    xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(factory);
    xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
}
```

The complete code can be see in the Gist above.

I'm not sure this solution would work if you only needed a few fields wrapped in CDATA. For that I think you would need to modify ToXmlGenerator, to make it aware of your model somehow (using annotations perhaps?) and then the generator would call `writeCData()` where necessary.

Comment: alot more complex then I was hoping for, but much cleaner than my hacking up of the actual physical text.

Comment: Agreed, I wish the Jackson code was a bit more flexible. Since they provide the ability to override factory classes, I don't understand why all the relevant classes are final. It would be even better if CData was supported natively with annotations.

Answer (score 15):

There is `@JacksonXmlCData` since 2.5. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml:

> `@JacksonXmlCData` allows specifying that the value of a property is to be serialized within a CData tag.

Comment: wow I don't need to do this anymore, but its really good to know

Comment: the doc says "Only use on String properties and String collections" : it does not work for a custom type like InnerObject

Comment: @Flyout91 When talking about "serialization to XML", CDATA is merely "how do I nicely represent the text". I'm not sure about why would someone want to care about CDATA in non-text context. CDATA is "I have text, and I want it to be text in my XML".

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any option to make output use CDATA sections.

But why should you need to use CDATA sections? In XML CDATA is not semantically different from regular text section. It only exists as convenience thing for manual editing.

Comment: Our esb requires it... I personally would never do it.

Comment: Ok. Not sure how this could be done -- in theory you might be able to sub-class `XMLOutputFactory`, to produce `XMLStreamWriter` instances that hi-jacks `writeCharacters()`, calls `writeCData` instead. Woodstox has some functionality to help delegate calls, that might work. But I can't think of default feature; there is the reverse ("output all text as CHARACTERS, even if instructed to use CDATA").

Comment: Oh -- you could also file a feature request for this for Jackson XML module. Implementing it there would actually be quite easy; calling `writeCData()` instead of `writeCharacters()`. As long as it'd be fine to use that for all textual writes.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just putting in a placeholder, marshelling both objects, then manipulated the strings by hand... not clean not pretty but it worked.